# JavaScript zoom image and center viewable area

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, zooming, center

I'm trying to create a zoom able image upon click of a button, however the image should be zoomed centered on the view able area, as the image may be bigger than the container.

I've created a fiddle here to illustrate what I want, I'd obviously usually hide the image outside the container, I'm not bothered about that part just now, also put in a border overlay to show the bounds of the container.

I've done the zoom part based on the image ratio, I just need to work out the new top and left css values and apply it to the image after the zoom.  Also the image is draggable, so once you move the image it must take into account the position of the image.

Basically, the centrol point of the image within the red container must remain the same after the zoom, so you are effectly zooming in on whatever is at the middle of the container.

http://jsfiddle.net/wFaFg/1/

```
why do you we need code to link to jsfiddle?
```

Thanks

edit:

http://jsfiddle.net/FU55w/

getting close with the above fiddle, but still not zooming completely on central point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found the solution,

It is slightly more complex than just finding out how much the image increased in size.

I work out the x & y value of the center point of the image within the container, by taking the left and top value, turning it positive then adding half the container width and height.

```
var x = Math.abs(image.position().left) + container.width() / 2
var y = Math.abs(image.position().top) + container.height() / 2
```

I work out the ratio of the image scale by dividing the new width by the old width, then I can multiply the x & y value by the ratio.

Then take the difference between the new x and y away from the current left and top.

```
image.position().left - (newX - x)
image.position().top - (newY - y)
```

Complete fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fbd2mk5q/

Comment: How can we drag the image inside the borders?

Answer (score 1):

Try the new fiddle based on your comment:

http://jsfiddle.net/wFaFg/6/

```
$("#zoom").on("click", function(e)
{
    var container = $("#container");
    var image = $("#container img");
    var curLeft = image.position().left;
    var curTop = image.position().top;
    var ratio = image.height() / image.width();

    image.css({
        height: image.height() + (20 * ratio),
        width: image.width() + (20 * ratio),
        left: curLeft - ((20 * ratio)/2),
        top: curTop - ((20 * ratio)/2)
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I forgot to say that the image is draggable, and it must always zoom from the center of the current position.  In the original fiddle you can drag the image if you drag the part from outside the container (the border div stops you dragging from inside it, not a problem for now)

Comment: OK let me get this straight. The fiddle image starts at left top of image. If I now drag it to display right bottom in the red adrea, and then click zoom, you want to zoom the image while the position stays at right bottom?

Comment: No, I want the center point of the image within the container to stay in the same position, so you are effectively zooming in on whatever is in the middle of the container (red box)

Comment: Hmmmmm still doesn't seem to zoom from the center to me

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FU55w/ should show how it isn't zooming on the center.  Place a point over the 'crosshair' and see that it isn't zooming on central point.

Comment: I take it this harder than expected

Comment: Yes it is. I typed out all variables and this should work (but it doesn't) http://jsfiddle.net/FU55w/4/

If the image get's 10 pixels wider, then the position should go 5 to the left. That's what this code does (I think), but still not getting good centralized zoom. Perhaps its a rounding issue

Comment: I think it's more to do with detecting x and y values of the point in which the crosshair is over the image, and using that when computing the left and top values but I'm not sure.